# Hiera: can't convert String into Hash, what could be the reason?

Tags: puppet, rpm, centos6, hiera

I've written a module which uses `rpm -e $package_name --nodeps` to remove a single RPM without it's dependencies.

I'm using Hiera and I've got `hiera_include("classes", [])` set in the Puppet server's `site.pp` file.

The module includes two configuration files, the first one is `init.pp`:

```
class rmpkg {
    $pkg_name = hiera_hash('rpm_name', undef)
        if $pkg_name != undef {
            create_resources("rmpack", $pkg_name)
        }
}
```

And `remove_rpm.pp`:

```
define rmpack ($rpm_name) {
exec { 'remove_rpm_${name}':
        command => "/bin/rpm -e ${rpm_name} --nodeps",
        path => "/bin/rpm",
        onlyif => "/bin/rpm -q --quiet ${rpm_name}",
 }
```

The relevant hiera file looks like so:

```
classes:
  - rmpkg

rpm_name:
    rpm_1: cups
```

I've also tried:

```
classes:
  - rmpkg

rpm_name:
    rpm_1:
      rpm: cups
```

When I run `puppet agent -t` on the affected client I receive the following error:

```
[root@itaitest ]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: can't convert String into Hash at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/rmpkg/manifests/init.pp:4 on node itaitest.nj.company.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
[root@itaitest ]#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$pkg_name = hiera_hash('rpm_name::rpm_1::rpm', undef)`

rpm_name on it's own will load a hash something like

{ 'rpm_1': { 'rpm' : 'cups' } }

passing that to your defined type will give the error you have reported

Comment: Thanks. It's now continuing to caching catalog etc... but cups rpm is not deleted... do you see anything in my code which could prevent it from working?

Comment: Also, the whole idea of using Hiera for this task is to allow using generic variables, if I specify `'remove_rpm::rpm1::rpm'` then only this package will work.. I want to be able to write more than 1 package for removal..

Comment: I agree, it seems to me that the second version of your hiera file looks correct.  In examples I have here there are 3 (probably not significant) differences with what I have that works and what you are doing.  1) the third arg to hiera_hash is {} not undef  2) the defined type is called like create_resources(modulename::function, $hash) 3) $title is used instead of $name in the defined types.  Sorry for the cargo cultish suggestion.  What version of puppet are you using btw?